# How to embedd a php generated table in Html email

Tags: php, html, email

I am attempting to include a table in the body of an HTML email that is generated through php. The HTML commands opens up outlook or any other client mailer and email the table to themselves.
The format of the table is totally lost when showing up in the body of the email.
Is there a way to keep the format of a table or at least a separation by columns? 
Thanks in advance

The html code is as follows:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $login_name; ?>?subject=Your Table &body=<?php echo $strip_table;?>" onclick="";return false;" title="Email list"><img src="email.jpg" width=250 height=90/></a>
```

The php `$strip_table` for the email body is generated by the following:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $event=$rows['Event'];
  $task=$rows['Task'];
  $day=$rows['Day'];
  $date=$rows['Date'];
  $hours=$rows['PlanHours'];
  $level=$rows['Level'];

  $table .="<tr>";
  $table .="<td>$event</td>";
  $table .="<td>$task</td>";
  $table .="<td>$day</td>";
  $table .="<td>$date</td>";
  $table .="<td>$hours</td>";
  $table .="<td>$level</td>";
  $table .="</tr><br>";
}
$table .="</table>";
$strip_table = strip_tags($table);
```

Following the appearance of the table in the email. Obviously missing the separation in columns, etc:

[image]

Whereas I am attempting to get the following format

[image]

Comment: The strip_tags will be removing all of the HTML that you generated, hence the terrible format in the email body!

Comment: Though, i don't believe you can add html to a message body using a mailto link.

Comment: You definitely should read what does `strip_tags` do